# NHibernate LINQ query Specified method is not supported error

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda

I am new to NHibernate and while exploring it I got into trouble with the following query which gives me a "Specified method is not supported." error, any ideas why?

```
var merchantSite = session.Query<MerchantSite>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Site.Id == SiteId);
var customers = session.Query<Customer>().Where(x => x.Transaction.Any<Transaction>(y => merchantSite.Transaction.Any<Transaction>(c => c.Id == y.Id))).ToList();
```

Both MerchantSite and Transaction have a list of objects of type Transaction.

There must be someone out there who has been in the similar situation, please share with us your experience, what should we do in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you do the ToList call, that's when nHibernate is building the necessary SQL to run the query and it's basically saying that it's having trouble translating that into a single SQL call.

Answer (score 0):

If x.Site is null, then you'd get "specific method is not supported." You could try writing

```
FirstOrDefault(x => x.Site != null && x.Site.Id == SiteId);
```

or using C# 6

```
FirstOrDefault(x => x.Site?.Id == SiteId);
```